# Redirect after sucess posting form

Tags: php

I have this code of php for the method of o the posted form.

**config.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');

function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
   $words = explode(' ', $string);
   return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    $title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $body=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
    $title=htmlentities($title);
    $body=htmlentities($body);

    $newtitle=string_limit_words($title, 6);

    $urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);

    $newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$newtitle);
    $date=date("Y/m/d");
    $url=$date.'/'.$newurltitle.'.html';


    mysql_query("insert into blog(title,body,url) values('$title','$body','$url')");

}
?>
```

---

With the code above, I successfully posted the form and I can find the file. However, after posting the form, the config.php just leave blank. What I want is it redirect to another page like congratz.html page.

**congratz.html**

```
 <body>
       <h2>CONGRATZ, YoOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY POST THE FORM TO THE DATABASE</h2>
 </body>
```

What I know to achieve this is to add the header line like:

```
  header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/congratz.html');
```

in the config.php.

However I am not sure how to do that or where to put the header in the config.php.

I am just learning php and self-taught. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: There are few ways to handle error: error_logs file, enabling error reporting right in the response. Past this to script to see an error `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the this after your query

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)//checking weather the query worked or not
{
    header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/congratz.html');
}
```

**So your whole code should look like this**

```
<?php
include('db.php');

function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
   $words = explode(' ', $string);
   return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    $title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $body=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
    $title=htmlentities($title);
    $body=htmlentities($body);

    $newtitle=string_limit_words($title, 6);

    $urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);

    $newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$newtitle);
    $date=date("Y/m/d");
    $url=$date.'/'.$newurltitle.'.html';


    mysql_query("insert into blog(title,body,url) values('$title','$body','$url')");
    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)//Checking weather the query worked or not
{
    header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/congratz.html');
}

}
?>
```

Also mysql is deprecitaed, learn mysqli or PDO

For mysqli function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

For PDO function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

And for learn about header check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: it works without the `if(mysql_affected_rows()>1)`. What's wrong? Btw, thanks for the references, I will keep them for studying.

Comment: @AlKasih it will work with out `if(mysql_affected_rows()>1)` the reason i added that line is this. Lets say in future the user try to be smart, and do some thing stupid. Your sanitazation will pass, but his data will not be inserted into database. Hence he wont be redirected to the success page. In shoort `if(mysql_affected_rows()>1)` checking the user input not your code as your code is fine. In short user will only go the the congrats page if every thing is fine. Thanks

Comment: I mean, with the complete code you give to me it doesn't work. But when I delete the if(mysql_affected_rows()>1) it works.

Comment: I think there is somethin you are missing there like typo or what.

Comment: `if(mysql_affected_rows()>1)` `if(mysql_affected_rows($connection)>1)` yah you are right `$connection` is a variable which you used to connect with the daabase. so have to change it. Sorry go `db.php` and get that variable

Comment: if you dont understand any thing ask again. Thanks

Comment: @AlKasih see the updated answer i had one typo as well `if(mysql_affected_rows()>1)` this should be this `if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)` means 1 should be zero. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the header after the query.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    $title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $body=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
    $title=htmlentities($title);
    $body=htmlentities($body);

    $newtitle=string_limit_words($title, 6);

    $urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);

    $newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$newtitle);
    $date=date("Y/m/d");
    $url=$date.'/'.$newurltitle.'.html';


    mysql_query("insert into blog(title,body,url) values('$title','$body','$url')");
    header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/congratz.html');

}
```

Comment: Please tick the check so other people will also learn from this. Thanks